# Effective techniques to take down a pack of Beowolfs

Tags: rwby-grimm-eclipse

Mainly my issue when playing the game is when I meet a **pack** of Beowolfs (More than 2 of them.), anything below 3 of them is fine for me. Somehow my main issue against them is this :

When I want to attack them, they mostly block my attacks, only causing my heavy attacks to deal damage. And when I attack them after a counter, the others would try and attack me too, which results me in having to quickly switch my target and also letting my combo attack gets canceled.

And that process keeps repeating which ends up in me not really doing much real damage to them (in a short amount of time) since I have to keep switching between targets so that I won't get attacked, ending up in me not finishing up my combo.

Can anyone advise how to quickly eliminate them smoothly as a pack without using ultimate ability?
Also, I currently use Ruby as my main character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of found a solution for myself for now :
Basically instead of me countering when the Beowolf attack, I will use my attack instead to cancel the Beowolf's attack, and end my attack early with a heavy AoE attack. ( A>A>H or A>A>A>H )
This had allowed me to do a lot of damage while being able to survive against a pack of Beowolfs.

If anyone have better suggestions, please post it too!

Answer (score 0):

With small groups of Beowolves (up to 5-6) it's possible to just circle-counter them, because the stun of the counter is long enough to keep all of them stunned while attacking one.

If you're fighting large groups (10-20) of Beowolves, for example when solo XP grinding on the highest difficulty, the most efficient tactic is to sprint and dodge around them and away from them to herd them into a large ball, then get enough of a lead to charge your heavy attack, discharge it into the fray and then immediately dodge out again while they're stunned, possibly performing finishers on enemies whose team attacks you triggered (if you're playing solo or as Ren) or using your ultimate to maximise AoE damage while within a high concentration of enemies (I recommend doing this in the air to not be killed during the casttime). This usually lets you in and out unharmed while doing decent AoE. Recommended for the tactic is the skill that gives you a higher team attack stun chance on heavy attacks.